# h12 error when mongoose try to connect to heroku mlab mongo db with node js why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

My code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("debug", true);
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

module.exports.User = require("./user");
module.exports.Profile = require("./profile");
module.exports.Lawyer = require('./lawyer');
```

when trying to connect to the MongoDB i get this H12 error (I changed some characters and removed the app name)

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/auth/signin" host=---------.herokuapp.com request_id=2942dabg6-d30c-43d5-b4d8-c45f435e6bgf56h fwd="217.160.71.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30230ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I tried every solution I could find on the web like getting MONGODB_URI and putting it instead of 'process.env' and others.

Comment: I read that when i should use db.once('open', function callback{}), but I didn't know how to implement it with module exports

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue try adding your host ip address on your mongodb IP whitelist.